# Image stream/byte array given path on user's computer in Azure Function App

Tags: azure-storage, azure-functions

I'm trying to make an HTTP-triggered function app **using Azure Function Apps (on Azure Portal)**, such that when user gives a full path to an image on his/her computer, the function will upload that local image to a blob storage. The request body looks something like this:

```
{
    "path": "C:\\Users\\myimage.jpg"
}
```

However, I'm stuck at even getting the file. I tried

```
var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```

but it says access to the path is denied.

I also tried the following in order to convert the image to byte[ ] later on.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Unfortunately, it says that the name 'Image' does not exist in the current context, even though I have already included `using System.Drawing;`.

What I suspect is that both of these methods work only when being ran on user's local computer itself instead of on cloud. On Azure cloud platform, the path specified by the user may refer to somewhere of cloud storage, and not the path on user's computer.

Any solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Azure Functions are running on different servers, do don't use the local file system. Instead, store the image in a blob you control and then supply the url to the Function, which can download and process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run Azure function on local, you could send request as above use the local path of your image. Here is the [tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51489.azure-functions-uploading-images-to-storage-blobs.aspx) you could refer to.

However, when you run your function on azure portal, the function run path change to `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`, so you could upload your file below `D:\home\site\wwwroot>` so it could read the file.